# Why is my JavaScript for calculator not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I don't know why my calculator isn't working and i have no idea what's
> wrong. I tried to find answer even here on stackoverflow, but didn't find anything. I think there might be some problem in JavaScript code. Also there is some error in JavaScript, but i can't find what is it. I think it could be the **integerDisplay** part. Could you please help? I put my code below. I'd be super
> grateful for any help or advice, beacuse I have no clue where's the issue.

```js
class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.clear()
    }

    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
    }

    appendNumber(number) {
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()     
    }

    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === '') return
        if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
            this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
    }

    compute() {
        let computation 
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if (isNaN(prev)  || isNaN(current)) return
        switch (this.operation) {
            case '+':
                computation = prev + current
                break
            case '-':
                computation = prev - current
                break
            case '*':
                computation = prev * current
                break
            case '÷':
                computation = prev / current
                break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation 
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
    }

    getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.'[1])
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
            integerDisplay = ''
        } else {
            integerDisplay integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', {
            maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
        }
        if (decimalDigits != null) {
            return `${integerDigits}.${decimalDigits}`
        } else {
          return integerDisplay
        }
    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = 
            this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
        if (this.operation != null) {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = 
                `${this.previousOperand} ${this.operation}`
        } else {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = '' 
        }
    }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const clearAllButton = document.querySelector('[data-clear-all]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

clearAllButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.delete()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');
    
        *, *::before, *::after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, yellow);
        }
    
        .calculator-grid {
            display: grid;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
            grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
        }
    
        .calculator-grid > button {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 2rem;
            border: 1px solid white;
            outline: none;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
        }
    
        .calculator-grid > button:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
        }
    
        .span-two {
            grid-column: span 2;
        }
    
        .output {
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-end;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    
        .output .previous-operand {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
    .output .current-operand {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator-grid">
        <div class="output">
            <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
            <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
        </div>
        <button data-clear-all class="span-two">AC</button>
        <button data-delete>DEL</button>
        <button data-operation>÷</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-operation>*</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operation>-</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-number>0</button>
        <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In line 67 of the JS code there's a `=` missing.

Comment: oh yh thanks i fixed that, but still got problem with my calculator not working as it should

Comment: `stringNumber.split('.'[1])` means `stringNumber.split(undefined)`. Did you mean `stringNumber.split('.')[1]`?

Comment: yh it prolly was just a missclick even tho i fixed it and i run it it still doesnt add numbers to the calculator and i have no clue why

Comment: could it be something with the numberButtons part or getDisplay part?

Answer (score -1):

Button hasn't any event Event Listener to change and update/action method

Please check original source.

Or add for each control(*, -, del ...) events.

For example for buttons with number

```
for (let i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++) {
  const btn = numberButtons[i];
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    calculator.appendNumber(this.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  });
}
// better to add event for parent block instead of for each child
```